# Unicode elements in list save to file

Tags: python, unicode

I have two questions:

1) What I have done wrong in the script below? The result in not encoded propertly and all non standard characters are stored incorrectly. When I print out data list it gives me a proper list of unicode types:

> [u'Est-ce que tu peux traduire \xc3\xa7a pour moi?                   \n                                  \n                                    \n                                                    Can                you                translate                this                for                me?'], [u'Chicago est tr\xc3\xa8s diff\xc3\xa9rente de Boston.                   \n                                  \n                                    \n                                                    Chicago                is                very                different                from                Boston.'],

After that I strip all extra spaces and next lines and result in file is like this (looks same when print and save to file):

> Est-ce que tu peux traduire Ã§a pour moi?;Can you translate this for me?
>   Chicago est trÃ¨s diffÃ©rente de Boston.;Chicago is very different from Boston.

2) What other than Python scripting langage would you recommend?

```
import requests
import unicodecsv, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import html5lib

countries = ["fr"]   #,"id","bn","my","chin","de","es","fr","hi","ja","ko","pt","ru","th","vi","zh"]

for country in countries:
    f = open("phrase_" + country + ".txt","w")
    w = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')


    toi = 1
    print country

    while toi<2:

        url = "http://www.englishspeak.com/"+ country +"/english-phrases.cfm?newCategoryShowed=" + str(toi) + "&sortBy=28"
        r = requests.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
        soup.unicode

        [s.extract() for s in soup('script')]
        [s.extract() for s in soup('style')]
        [s.extract() for s in soup('head')]
        [s.extract() for s in soup("table" , { "height" : "102" })]
        [s.extract() for s in soup("td", { "class" : "copyLarge"})]
        [s.extract() for s in soup("td", { "width" : "21%"})]
        [s.extract() for s in soup("td", { "colspan" : "3"})]
        [s.extract() for s in soup("td", { "width" : "25%"})]
        [s.extract() for s in soup("td", { "class" : "blacktext"})]
        [s.extract() for s in soup("div", { "align" : "center"})]

        data = []

        rows = soup.find_all('tr', {"class": re.compile("Data.")})

        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
            data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

        wordsList = []

        for index, item in enumerate(data):
            str_tmp = "".join(data[index]).encode('utf-8')
            str_tmp =  re.sub(r'  +\n\s+', ';', str_tmp)
            str_tmp =  re.sub(r'  +', ' ', str_tmp)
            wordsList.append(str_tmp.decode('utf-8'))
            print str_tmp

        w.writerow(wordsList)

        toi += 1
```

Comment: i couldn't understand your first question ! whats the problem ?

Comment: When I print or save to file output data it has messed up unicode chars like this: **rÃ¨s diffÃ©rente** I have tried everything and cannot find solution for this.

Second question is what other language than Python (that works good with unicode) I could use for project like this?

Comment: Don't understand, why do you encode str_tmp for regular expression substitution? And what is the sense of all these list-comprehensions you never use?

Comment: Didn't read through all the codes, but for the codec part, you should use `ISO-8859-1` to do the encode

Comment: why are you using  list comps if  you don't actually want a list?

Comment: @Daniel
& Padraic Cunningham
This is my first ever Python code. I used list as I thought this was the easiest way to manipulate it and output the way I wanted.

The list-comprehension part I found this piece of code on stackoverflow and it worked for me to get the data to form I needed - only text wanted stripped of html tags

If you can give me some suggestions on how it should be written I would really appreciate it.

Comment: About the encode/decode part, without this I was getting UnicodeEncodeErrors. And I didn't find a way to do regex substitution on a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `r.text` not `r.content` because content are the bytes and text is the decoded text:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write utf-8 encoded to file:

```
with open("out.txt","w") as f:
     for d in data:
         d = " ".join(d).encode("utf-8")
         d = re.sub(r'\n\s+', ';', d)
         d = re.sub(r'  +', ' ', d)
         f.write(d)
```

Output:

```
Fais attention en conduisant. ;Be careful driving.Fais attention. ;Be careful.Est-ce que tu peux traduire ça pour moi? ;Can you translate this for me?Chicago est très différente de Boston. ;Chicago is very different from Boston.Ne t'inquiète pas. ;Don't worry.Tout le monde le sais. ;Everyone knows it.Tout est prêt. ;Everything is ready.Excellent. ;Excellent.De temps en temps. ;From time to time.Bonne idée. ;Good idea.Il l'aime beaucoup. ;He likes it very much.A l'aide! ;Help!Il arrive bientôt. ;He's coming soon.Il a raison. ;He's right.Il est très ennuyeux. ;He's very annoying.Il est très célèbre. ;He's very famous.Comment ça va? ;How are you?Comment va le travail? ;How's work going?Dépêche-toi! ;Hurry!J'ai déjà mangé. ;I ate already.Je ne vous entends pas. ;I can't hear you.Je ne sais pas m'en servir. ;I don't know how to use it.Je ne l'aime pas. ;I don't like him.Je ne l'aime pas. ;I don't like it.Je ne parle pas très bien. ;I don't speak very well.Je ne comprends pas. ;I don't understand.Je n'en veux pas. ;I don't want it.Je ne veux pas ça. ;I don't want that.Je ne veux pas te déranger. ;I don't want to bother you.Je me sens bien. ;I feel good.Je sors du travail à six heures. ;I get off of work at 6.J'ai mal à la tête. ;I have a headache.J'espère que votre femme et vous ferez un bon voyage. ;I hope you and your wife have a nice trip.Je sais. ;I know.Je l'aime. ;I like her.J'ai perdu ma montre. ;I lost my watch.Je t'aime. ;I love you.J'ai besoin de changer de vêtements. ;I need to change clothes.J'ai besoin d'aller chez moi. ;I need to go home.Je veux seulement un en-cas. ;I only want a snack.Je pense que c'est bon. ;I think it tastes good.Je pense que c'est très bon. ;I think it's very good.Je pensais que les vêtements étaient plus chers. ;I thought the clothes were cheaper.J'allais quitter le restaurant quand mes amis sont arrivés. ;I was about to leave the restaurant when my friends arrived.Je voudrais faire une promenade. ;I'd like to go for a walk.Si vous avez besoin de mon aide, faites-le-moi savoir s'il vous plaît. ;If you need my help, please let me know.Je t'appellerai vendredi. ;I'll call you when I leave.Je reviendrai plus tard. ;I'll come back later.Je paierai. ;I'll pay.Je vais le prendre. ;I'll take it.Je t'emmenerai à l'arrêt de bus. ;I'll take you to the bus stop.Je suis un Américain. ;I'm an American.Je nettoie ma chambre. ;I'm cleaning my room.J'ai froid. ;I'm cold.Je viens te chercher. ;I'm coming to pick you up.Je vais partir. ;I'm going to leave.Je vais bien, et toi? ;I'm good, and you?Je suis content. ;I'm happy.J'ai faim. ;I'm hungry.Je suis marié. ;I'm married.Je ne suis pas occupé. ;I'm not busy.Je ne suis pas marié. ;I'm not married.Je ne suis pas encore prêt. ;I'm not ready yet.Je ne suis pas sûr. ;I'm not sure.Je suis désolé, nous sommes complets. ;I'm sorry, we're sold out.J'ai soif. ;I'm thirsty.Je suis très occupé. Je n'ai pas le temps maintenant. ;I'm very busy. I don't have time now.Est-ce que Monsieur Smith est un Américain? ;Is Mr. Smith an American?Est-ce que ça suffit? ;Is that enough?C'est plus long que deux kilomètres. ;It's longer than 2 miles.Je suis ici depuis deux jours. ;I've been here for two days.J'ai entendu dire que le Texas était beau comme endroit. ;I've heard Texas is a beautiful place.Je n'ai jamais vu ça avant. ;I've never seen that before.Juste un peu. ;Just a little.Juste un moment. ;Just a moment.Laisse-moi vérifier. ;Let me check.laisse-moi y réfléchir. ;Let me think about it.Allons voir. ;Let's go have a look.Pratiquons l'anglais. ;Let's practice English.Pourrais-je parler à madame Smith s'il vous plaît? ;May I speak to Mrs. Smith please?Plus que ça. ;More than that.Peu importe. ;Never mind.La prochaine fois. ;Next time.Non, merci. ;No, thank you.Non. ;No.N'importe quoi. ;Nonsense.Pas récemment. ;Not recently.Pas encore. ;Not yet.Rien d'autre. ;Nothing else.Bien sûr. ;Of course.D'accord. ;Okay.S'il vous plaît remplissez ce formulaire. ;Please fill out this form.S'il vous plaît emmenez-moi à cette adresse. ;Please take me to this address.S'il te plaît écris-le. ;Please write it down.Vraiment? ;Really?Juste ici. ;Right here.Juste là. ;Right there.A bientôt. ;See you later.A demain. ;See you tomorrow.A ce soir. ;See you tonight.Elle est jolie. ;She's pretty.Désolé de vous déranger. ;Sorry to bother you.Arrête! ;Stop!Tente ta chance. ;Take a chance.Réglez ça dehors. ;Take it outside.Dis-moi. ;Tell me.Merci Mademoiselle. ;Thank you miss.Merci Monsieur. ;Thank you sir.Merci beaucoup. ;Thank you very much.Merci. ;Thank you.Merci pour tout. ;Thanks for everything.Merci pour ton aide. ;Thanks for your help.Ça a l'air super. ;That looks great.Ça sent mauvais. ;That smells bad.C'est pas mal. ;That's alright.Ça suffit. ;That's enough.C'est bon. ;That's fine.C'est tout. ;That's it.Ce n'est pas juste. ;That's not fair.Ce n'est pas vrai. ;That's not right.C'est vrai. ;That's right.C'est dommage. ;That's too bad.C'est trop. ;That's too many.C'est trop. ;That's too much.Le livre est sous la table. ;The book is under the table.Ils vont revenir tout de suite. ;They'll be right back.Ce sont les mêmes. ;They're the same.Ils sont très occupés. ;They're very busy.Ça ne marche pas. ;This doesn't work.C'est très difficile. ;This is very difficult.C'est très important. ;This is very important.Essaie-le/la. ;Try it.Très bien, merci. ;Very good, thanks.Nous l'aimons beaucoup. ;We like it very much.Voudriez-vous prendre un message s'il vous plaît? ;Would you take a message please?Oui, vraiment. ;Yes, really.Vos affaires sont toutes là. ;Your things are all here.Tu es belle. ;You're beautiful.Tu es très sympa. ;You're very nice.Tu es très intelligent. ;You're very smart.
```

Also you don't actually use the data in your list comps so they seem a little pointless:

Comment: Thank you I will use that writer its much easier implementation

Comment: @user1695182, no worries, you should use .content and let requests handle the encoding.